# How does c allocate memory to constant string?

Tags: c++, string, allocation, memcpy, ld-preload

I want to change **malloc**, **memcpy** and **free** function and use this libhooker with LD_PRELOAD. 
I change them, and test them for some test cases. but in one of them, my code doesn't work correct and don't know why.
Test Case:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

my code output:

```
malloc[0x8229170-0x8229182]
[memcpy] source address 0x8048850 is not allocated.
free(0x8229170)
```

I don't know how c allocate memory for constant string and why my code is wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: string? do you mean c++?

Comment: You are going to provide some background info. How does running that program produce that output? String literals are not allocated by `malloc`. It's part of the data segment (implementation dependent) and not managed by `malloc/free`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go

Answer (score 5):

String constants typically get allocated in DATA section of a program. This is usually marked as read-only and the location offset is defined at compile time.

This memory is not usually allocated by `malloc`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with memcpy, but you can not assume that everything you want to memcpy will have been allocated using `malloc`. For instance, everything allocated on the stack. Everything in the data section. Everything allocated using a custom allocator (which may live on the stack). Also you need to be aware of `calloc`, `alloc` and `realloc` too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it was so helpful :)